# if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load

Tags: c#, javascript, html

```
<script src="/Website/ScriptResource.axd?d=FEJ1d69wZhASKJvcaA0Wek5gZBqP6bkU2N5CUh1DZqBYLx9ewPx7pqd2n0htAexVwpCaJmuaKJh8dePjt_C6j5e4_AOkZBwko7p7c8F1iiI1&amp;t=ffffffffec2d9970" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
//]]>
</script>
```

i am Getting this rendered HTML for converting to PDF But due to this error the Page PDF is Not converted Completely Kindly anybody help me .I searched a lot on GOOGLE but Got same rendered HTML.
Please Any anybody help me regarding this problem

This is my server side Code for Rendering Html of the Page

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter twr = new StreamWriter(mem);
        HtmlTextWriter myWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(twr);
        base.Render(myWriter);
        myWriter.Flush();
        myWriter.Dispose();
        StreamReader strmRdr = new StreamReader(mem);
        strmRdr.BaseStream.Position = 0;
        string pageContent = strmRdr.ReadToEnd();

        strmRdr.Dispose();
        mem.Dispose();
        writer.Write(pageContent);
}
```

Comment: Is this a strong enough argument for non-intrusive javascript?

Comment: What is your server side code that generates this text?